# How to set conditional multiple detail panels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I would like to have multiple detailpanels without knowing a priori how many. So I thought of passing properties (expandibleDetails and showParameters) that take on the values ​​of true or false: if true I want the panel, if false no. The problem is that, if I render null because the property has value "false", material-table gives the error "m-table-body-row.js:221 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of null".

```
detailPanel={expandibleDetails ? [{
  tooltip: "Show Details",
  render: (rowData) => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          height: '250px',
        }}
      >
        <Textarea
          id={`${ rowData.tableData.id }-details`}
          value={rowData.details}
        />
      </div>
    );
  },
}, showParameters ? {
  tooltip: "Show parameters",
  render: (rowData) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Textarea
          id={`${rowData.tableData.id}-parameters`}
          value={rowData.parameters}
        />
      </div>
    );
  },
} : null] : []}
```

After that I set a render method that doesn't do anything but panel icon still appear and I don't want the relative panel...

```
detailPanel={expandibleDetails ? [{
  tooltip: "Show Details",
  render: (rowData) => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          height: '250px',
        }}
      >
      <Textarea
        id={`${ rowData.tableData.id }-details`}
        value={rowData.details}
      />
    </div>
  );
},
}, showParameters ? {
  tooltip: "Show parameters",
  render: (rowData) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Textarea
        id={`${rowData.tableData.id}-parameters`}
        value={rowData.parameters}
      />
    </div>
  );
},
} : {render: () => {} : []}
```

Also this code seems quite unreadable, is there a way to make it better? I didn't find a way, I created an external function and then passed into detailPanel but I get errors...

```
const detailedArray = () => {
  let arr= [];
  if (expandibleDetails) {
    arr.push({
      tooltip: "Show Details",
      render: (rowData) => {
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            height: '250px',
            }}
          >
          <Textarea
            id={`${ rowData.tableData.id }-details`}
            value={rowData.details}
          />
        </div>
      },
    });
  }
  if (showParameters) {
    arr.push(...)
  }
  return arr;
};


detailPanel={detailArray}
```

Meanwhile, thanks to anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way. I post it in case someone needs it. I used the spread operator in order to obtain an object in case of true or nothing in case of false.

```
detailPanel={expandibleDetails ? [{
  tooltip: "Show Details",
  render: (rowData) => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          height: '250px',
        }}
      >
      <Textarea
        id={`${ rowData.tableData.id }-details`}
        value={rowData.details}
      />
    </div>
  );
},
}, 
...(showParameters ? [{
  tooltip: "Show parameters",
  render: (rowData) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Textarea
        id={`${rowData.tableData.id}-parameters`}
        value={rowData.parameters}
      />
    </div>
  );
},
}] : {}),
```